# Javascript onclick dynamic for loop get a hold of index

Tags: javascript, for-loop, dynamic, element, appendchild

Hello I have a problem gettig a hold of the index in the following code:

```
Contacts.push("test1 test 4232352");
Contacts.push("test2 test2 5435345");
for(var i = 0; i < Contacts.length; i++){

            var res = Contacts[i].split(" ");               
            var font = document.createElement("FONT");
            font.innerHTML = res[0] + " " + res[1];
            font.style.marginLeft = "10px";
            font.onclick = () => { console.log(i); }; 
            document.getElementById("contacts_collection").appendChild(font);               
}
```

in my mind it should print the index of the element I click on, but instead nomatter which of the 2 I click, it always prints '2'.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the delclaration of `i` using the statement `var`.

An alternative is declaring `i` using the statement `let`:

```
for(let i = 0; i < Contacts.length; i++){}
    ^^^
```

Or, you can use [**IIFE**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) to keep the current value of `i`:

```js
var Contacts = ["test1 test 4232352", "test2 test2 5435345"];
for (var i = 0; i < Contacts.length; i++) {
  var res = Contacts[i].split(" ");
  var font = document.createElement("FONT");
  font.innerHTML = "<b>" + res[0] + " " + res[1] + "</b>";
  font.style.marginLeft = "10px";
  
  font.onclick = ((index) => () => {
    console.log(index);
  })(i);
  
  document.body.appendChild(font);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) for your array.

**DEMO**

> In ES5

```js
var Contacts = ["test1 test 4232352", "test2 test2 5435345"],
  font = '';


Contacts.forEach(function(v, i) {
  v = v.split(" ");
  font = document.createElement("FONT");
  font.innerHTML = '<b>' + v[0] + ' ' + v[1] + ' </b><br>';
  font.setAttribute("style", "margin-left:10px; cursor:pointer");
  font.index = i;
  font.onclick = function(e) {
    console.log(e.target.parentElement.index);
  };
  document.getElementById('mydiv').appendChild(font);
});
```

```html
<div id="mydiv"></div>
```

> In ES6

```js
const Contacts = ["test1 test 4232352", "test2 test2 5435345"];


Contacts.forEach((v, i) => {
  v = v.split(" ");
  let font = document.createElement("FONT");
  font.innerHTML = `<b>${v[0]} ${v[1]}</b><br>`;
  font.setAttribute("style", "margin-left:10px; cursor:pointer");
  font.index = i;
  font.onclick = (e => {
    console.log(e.target.parentElement.index);
  });
  document.getElementById('mydiv').appendChild(font);
});
```

```html
<div id="mydiv"></div>
```

You can also use **[`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)** statement for array iterates.

**DEMO**

```js
var Contacts = ["test1 test 4232352", "test2 test2 5435345"],
  font = '',v;


for(let i in Contacts){
  v = Contacts[i].split(" ");
  font = document.createElement("FONT");
  font.innerHTML = '<b>' + v[0] + ' ' + v[1] + ' </b><br>';
  font.setAttribute("style", "margin-left:10px; cursor:pointer");
  font.index = i;
  font.onclick = function(e) {
    console.log(e.target.parentElement.index);
  };
  document.getElementById('mydiv').appendChild(font);
};
```

```html
<div id="mydiv"></div>
```